# Java/Tomcat has not enough permission to execute 'java'

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat, servlets, permissions

I have the following code running in one of my Java-Servlets on my Tomcat server on Ubuntu:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( "java", "-jar", "test.jar", Integer.toString( jobId ), Integer.toString( software ), Integer.toString( entryPoint ), application );
pb.directory( new File( "/home/user/Folder" ) );
proc = pb.start();
```

But in line three I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java" (in directory "/home/user/Folder"): error=13, Keine Berechtigung
```

It is german and means, that it doesn't have enough rights to execute 'java'.

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

this means that the user who starts the tomcat server does not have permissions to launch java process inside /home/user/Folder.

check who's running tomcat with:

```
ps aux | grep tomcat
```

either change the owner of /home/user/Folder so that it's owned by the user who runs the tomcat or adjust the file permissions accordingly

to change the owner of the directory you execute the following:

```
chown -R tomcat /home/user/Folder
```

to add permissions (so that tomcat can access the folder) you execute the following:

```
chmod -R o+rwx /home/user/Folder
```

**Note!** you only need to choose one method, not both.

Comment: I think it is the same user that runs both. If I run the command you gave me, where do I see from which user tomcat runs?

Comment: there is my output http://pastebin.com/t0EEX8y0 does that mean it is a user called tomcat7 ? :D I didn't knew this one exists.

Comment: yup, that's tomcat user. If you've installed the tomcat through a package manager you'll get a tomcat user as well.

Comment: when doing 'ls -l' I get this: `drwxr-xrwx 5 tomcat7 raphael     4096 Jun 30 18:25 FolderName`

Comment: Maybe it is more a problem of having not the rights to run 'java', instead of missing rights to exectue the jar in the folder?

Comment: Where is test.jar located? Is this file owned by tomcatuser?

Comment: that's what I get from 'ls- l': `-rwxr-xrwx 1 tomcat7 raphael 3079290 Jun 30 18:25 test.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Possible cause: AFAIR from your other question, you use a Linux machine, so there can be (besides the standard Unix security) also [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) in action, which allows to specify further restrictions. And it is quite possible, that there is a restriction imposed on tomcat (or even java itself), that prevents it from starting other processes (either all, or from a specified list).

Comment: I haven't got selinux installed. At least if I call `getenforce` I get a message, to install selinux-utils.